# How to find max length in list of string using streams in Java?

Tags: java, list, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a class like below:

```
public class A
{
    String name;
    String getName(){return name;}
}
```

And I also have a list like below:

```
List<A> list_a = new ArrayList<>();
//add n objects into list_a
```

Right now I would like to find the max length of object which is in list_a using streams in Java. I have created code like below:

```
final int max_len = list_a.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(A::getName::length));
```

But it does not work, I mean it is something bad with syntax. Could you help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are using isn't [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Lambda looks like  `(arguments) -> action`. What you have in `A::getName` is [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), but additional `::length` is not part of its syntax.

Instead of `A::getName::length` you can use lambda like `a -> a.getName().length()`.

But your code has yet another problem. Code

```
list_a.stream()
      .max(Comparator.comparingInt(A::getName::length));
```

is handling streams of `A` and `max` method called on `Stream<A>` will result in `Optional<A>` not `int`. It is `Optional` because there is a chance that `list_a` can be empty which means that there will be no valid result.

If you want to get OptionalInt you would need to `map` `Stream<A>` to `Stream<String>` and then `map` it to `Stream of int`s first. Then you can call its `max()` method and get:

```
OptionalInt maxOpt  = list_a.stream()
                            .map(A::getName)
                            .mapToInt(String::length)
                            .max();
```

When you already have `OptionalInt` you can use it to check if value there `isPresent()` and get it via `getAsInt()`. You can also use `orElse(defaultValueIfEmpty)` like

```
int max = maxOpt.orElse(-1); //will return value held by maxOpt, or -1 if there is no value
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `IntStream` as you're just looking for the max length:

```
OptionalInt oi = list_a.stream()
                 .map(A::getName)
                 .mapToInt(String::length)
                 .max()

final int max_len = oi.orElse(0); //defaulting to 0
```

If you need to use a custom comparator, you will need a lambda expression:

```
final int max_len = list_a.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> 
                     a.getName().length())) //need a lambda
                .map(A::getName)
                .map(String::length)
                .orElse(0); //defaulting to 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-):

```
A a = Collections.max(list_a, Comparator.comparing(obj -> obj.getName().length()));
int maxLen = a.getName().length();
```

Keep in mind that `Collections.max` throws `NoSuchElementException` if the collection is empty. If you don't want it, use the approach with `OptionalInt` like in @Pshemo's answer.